# Sorting for Custom column in grid view in Yii

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii

I have to check no of products quantity from other table and display it in current grid view. So i created one function in model for getting count of that column.

But my question is **How can I sort that custom column (checked_kpl) in grid view**.

Here is my code.

**MODEL**

```
public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
    $criteria->compare('purchase_order_id', $this->purchase_order_id);
    $criteria->compare('product_id', $this->product_id);
    $criteria->compare('unit_price', $this->unit_price, true);
    $criteria->compare('qty', $this->qty, true);
    $criteria->compare('cost_price', $this->cost_price, true);
    $criteria->compare('customs_percent', $this->customs_percent, true);
    $criteria->compare('discount_percent', $this->discount_percent, true);
    $criteria->compare('notes', $this->notes, true);
    $criteria->compare('created_at', $this->created_at, true);
    $criteria->compare('updated_at', $this->updated_at, true);

   return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
   ));
   }
}




public function getCheckedKpl() {
    $checked_kpl = 0;
    if (!empty($this->purchaseOrderArrivals)) {
        foreach ($this->purchaseOrderArrivals as $eachArrival) {
            $checked_kpl += $eachArrival->qty;
        }
    }
    return $checked_kpl;
}
```

**NOTE:** 
- purchaseOrderArrivals is another model. I already set relation with this model.
- getCheckedKpl function is giving me count of product quantity.

**VIEW** - In view I put this code in gridview widget for display column.

```
    array(
            'name' => 'checked_kpl',
            'value' => '$data->getCheckedKpl()',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'class' => 'DataColumn'
         ),
```

Any help will appreciate. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Model extends CActiveRecord {
  // Adding attribute to work with SQL query
  public $checked_kpl;

  public function attributeLabels(){
    // Prettify column name
    return array( 'checked_kpl' => 'Checked kpl' );
  }

  public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    // Count subquery like this
    // SELECT COUNT(*) as checked_kpl, id FROM {{table}} GROUP BY param
    // Condition like this
    // ( q1.id=t.id )
    $criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN (/* **HERE IS A COUNT SUBQUERY** */) as q1 ON(/* **HERE IS A CONDITION** */)";
    $criteria->select = array( '*', new CDbExpression("q1.checked_kpl as checked_kpl") );

    // ... your criteria here

    // Adding custom sort data
    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'checked_kpl' => array(
            'asc' => 'q1.checked_kpl',
            'desc' => 'q1.checked_kpl DESC'
        )
    );

    return new CActiveDataProvider( $this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort' => $sort,
    ) );
  }

}
```